# Unable to add logo on actionbar android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

Hello I am new to Android and I am trying to add a logo and a searchview in my actionbar of every activity. I tried to implement the logo on one of my activity but I get this error and the app crashes. Can someone tell me how to get rid of this? and is there any other way to do what I am trying to do ?

**I resized the icon directly from this website** https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Error

```
02-27 00:58:28.859 13851-13851/com.golstars.www.glostars E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.golstars.www.glostars, PID: 13851
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.golstars.www.glostars/com.golstars.www.glostars.MainFeed}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.golstars.www.glostars.MainFeed$override.onCreate(MainFeed.java:96)
                                                                               at com.golstars.www.glostars.MainFeed$override.access$dispatch(MainFeed.java)
                                                                               at com.golstars.www.glostars.MainFeed.onCreate(MainFeed.java:0)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

My mainfeed onCreate method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_feed);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_action_logoandtext);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

activity_main_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.golstars.www.glostars.MainFeed">



    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_test"

        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/fabs"
        />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.golstars.www.glostars">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainFeed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_feed"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".user_profile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Fabs"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".testfeed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".notification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".upload"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".edit_profile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".competitionUser"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_competition_user"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".competitionAll"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_competition_all"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".imagefullscreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image_full_screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".commentModel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comment_model"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `onCreate`, set the `toolbar` first

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_action_logoandtext);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```